# C# List of different types of objects derivated from same parent and custom properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections, covariance

I'm tring to create a list of different types object that derivated from the same parent and access its custom properties.

These are my classes:

```
    abstract class Signal
    {
    }

    abstract class Signal<T>:Signal
    {
        public T Value { get ; set; }

         public Signal(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    class scalar_signal : Signal<int>
    {
        public scalar_signal(int value):base(value)
        {
        }
    }

    class array_byte_signal: Signal<byte[]>
    {
        public array_byte_signal(byte[] value):base(value)
        {
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Join("; ", Value);
        }
    }
```

And this is my program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var signals = new List<Signal>();

        signals.Add(new scalar_signal(3));
        signals.Add(new array_byte_signal(new Byte[] { 0, 1 }));

        foreach (var signal in signals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(signal.Value); //Compilation error: Value is not defined in Signal
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm able to create a list of different types of signals but I'm not able to access their properties.

I really need to have only one list (or any other collection) with all my signals becuase later on it will be easier to process.

I have to implement one class for each type of signals as they need to implement a custom behavior depending of the type T. T could be also a class representing a complex number, matrix, etc.

I have read about Covariance and contravariance but I do not see how this could help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are fine with enumerating all types by hand you can use `pattern matching` via [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements) statements.

Comment: could you please post a more realistic example of how you want to use the `Value` ? or at least describe it? It is important for the solution of your problem. There are several ways to tackle it. I guess you want more than simply print it to console

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(signal.Value)` is bad example of how you want to use. To just print string - use similar approach as `ToString`: add abstract method to base class returning string.

Comment: you will probably have very context dependent usages of this value. Please post 2 different contextes in which you will use the value.

Comment: @MongZhu and Sinatr you are both right, I missed the context of my problem (this is my first question in stackoverflow I did not want to complicate things a lot). Indeed I need to be able not only to read "Value" but also write it.  I'm looking something as python paradigm even if I'm aware that c# is strongly typed language.

Comment: actually you probably need to step back and ask yourself, why do I need all these different objects in a single collection?

Comment: @EdgarCGarzon you will find that my answer, answers ur q tho hehe just as an FYI even if you have chosen to change your design.

Answer (score 0):

this is because

when you looping

```
foreach (var signal in signals)
{
     Console.WriteLine(signal.Value); //Compilation error: Value is not defined in Signal
}
```

the type is Signal

which as you now has no property.

what you need to do it ask it if its able to be something else,

```
foreach (var signal in signals)
{
   //#6
   if(signal  is scalar_signal)
   {
       var typeCast = (scalar_signal)signal;
       Console.WriteLine(typeCast .Value);
   }

   //#7.2 +
   if(signal  is scalar_signal valueTypeName)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(valueTypeName.Value);
   }
}
```

this should help